# How can I convert an integer variable into a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, integer

I am trying to convert a integer variable into a string in Javascript in order to add the number as an index in an object
for example

```
var objectIndex = 1
var value = 1.00
var object = {}

object.(string of object index) = (string of value with .00)
```

to get:

```
{ "1":"1.00" }
```

Comment: what is your issue ?

Comment: 1 + ".00" is "1.00"...

Comment: How can I get the integer to be the index of the object?

Comment: You might just want to set the index using square brackets 'object[objectIndex] = value'

Comment: that worked. also I needed the value.toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the trailing zeros in your string you want to use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
var objectIndex = 1;
var value = 1.00;
var myObject = {};

myObject[objectIndex.toString()] = value.toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = myObject[1];
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

The `.toString()` is really not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
   index = index+"";
   object[index] = (value.toFixed(2));
```

concatenating an integer to a "" will turn that number to string , although types are very flexible in javascript

Comment: js uses '+' to concatenate strings

Comment: Sorry , I used PHP concatenating operator

Comment: so you just stored "1" now

Comment: All Javascript codes will be downloaded by client browser , so keep in mind that always search for smaller code